# using VB.NET Shared Property in inline-code: `<% =<property> %>`

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

i'm using `Shared Property` to add some text to a `Div`.

step of my procedure is:

1. define a `Shared Property submitted= "not submitted"` in `myclass.vb` .
2. create a `mymasterpage.Master` with a div:
   `<div><%=submited%></div>`
3. create a `page1.aspx` with this code-behind:

   ```
   Protected Sub Page_Load (...)
   If action="submitted" then
   submitted="submitted"
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

So far, everything is fine, but the problem is that when `Master` loads again , the `submited` keeps its value and will show:

`<div>submitted</div>`

i need to one time that specified `submitted` to `"submitted"` ,next time that `submited` called, it returns `"not submited"` (i.e. it's orginal value)

`<div>not submitted</div>`

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use a `Shared` variable or property for this.**

A `Shared` (`static` in C#) variable is shared across all users of your web application. Imagine two users A and B accessing your web site at the same moment. What you are doing could cause user A to see something that was supposed to be for user B, and vice versa. You wouldn't want that, do you?

The solution is simple: Don't make the property `Shared`. If you have trouble accessing an instance (= non-shared) property from within your code, I suggest that you open a separate question on that. Making the property shared is *not* a good solution.

Comment: "A Shared variable is shared across all users of your web application" is cool point! but what can i do when only `Shared Property` is accessible in inline-code?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: Regular (non-shared) properties **are** accessible from inline code. As I said in my answer: If you have a problem accessing a non-shared property, ask a new SO question about that (with a minimal example demonstrating the problem).

Comment: thank, i found solution by using a `Class` with it's `Public Property` by `New` constructor and `<%@ MasterType TypeName="namespace" %>` .